# How to make xargs append trailing arguments with -n?

Tags: xargs

xargs is good at inserting initial arguments:

```
seq 0 10 | xargs -n 3 echo foo
```

produces this output:

```
foo 0 1 2
foo 3 4 5
foo 6 7 8
foo 9 10
```

What about when I also want trailing arguments?
That is, what command:

```
seq 0 10 | xargs -n 3 <WHAT GOES HERE?>
```

will produce the following desired output:

```
foo 0 1 2 bar
foo 3 4 5 bar
foo 6 7 8 bar
foo 9 10 bar
```

I tried the following:

```
seq 0 10 | xargs -n 3 -I {} echo foo {} bar
```

which is almost right, except that it apparently forces 1 item per command line, which isn't what I want:

```
foo 0 bar
foo 1 bar
foo 2 bar
foo 3 bar
foo 4 bar
foo 5 bar
foo 6 bar
foo 7 bar
foo 8 bar
foo 9 bar
foo 10 bar
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After figuring this out with a head-start from @netniV's answer,
I now see that the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) actually contains an example
showing how to do it:

> ```
> xargs sh -c 'emacs "$@" < /dev/tty' emacs
> ```
>
> Launches  the  minimum  number of copies of Emacs needed, one after the
>   other, to edit the files listed on xargs' standard input.  This example
>   achieves the same effect as BSD's -o option, but in a more flexible and portable way.

And the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#Shell_trick) shows a similar technique, with an explanation of the dummy arg at the end:

> Another way to achieve a similar effect is to use a shell as the launched command, and deal with the complexity in that shell, for
>   example:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir ~/backups
> $ find /path -type f -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'for filename; do cp -a "$filename" ~/backups; done' bash
> ```
>
> The word `bash` at the end of the line is interpreted by `bash -c` as special parameter `$0`. If the word bash weren't present, the name of
>   the first matched file would be assigned to `$0` and the file wouldn't
>   be copied to `~/backups`. Any word can be used instead of `bash`, but
>   since `$0` usually expands to the name of the shell or shell script
>   being executed, `bash` is a good choice.

So, here's how to do it:

```
seq 0 10 | xargs -n 3 sh -c 'echo foo "$@" bar' some_dummy_string
```

The output is as desired:

```
foo 0 1 2 bar
foo 3 4 5 bar
foo 6 7 8 bar
foo 9 10 bar
```

Comment: Do you know the signifigance of the dummy string? If you omit it then the first entry is omitted from the results.

Comment: @infoclogged see the discussion of the word "bash" at the end of the line in the excerpt above; that's the dummy argument in that example.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 12):

Use the -i parameter of xargs such as:

```
ls -1 | xargs -t -i echo "Found {} file"
```

Note that the -t is only there to show the command that will be issued. When running live, leave off the -t parameter.

The `{}` is replaced by the actual argument.  Note, that this does mean each command is run only once per file. Not as a group of files. If you need to use a different replace string, specify it after the -i

```
ls -1 | xargs -t -i[] xargs echo "Found []{} file"
```

Would keep `{}` after the filename which is now replaced on the occurance of `[]`

#### To achieve desired output

Create a script file called runme.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "foo $@ bar"
```

Make sure to chmod +X and then use

```
seq 0 10 | xargs -n 3 ./runme.sh
```

This would produce

```
foo tests tree.php user_admin.php bar
foo user_domains.php user_group_admin.php utilities.php bar
foo vdef.php bar
```

Comment: Hi @netniV, I already know how to get one item per command; that's not what I want.  I need the items to be grouped.  Can you make it output exactly what I described as my "desired output"?

Comment: There is no way to do that without writing your own intermediary script and call that from xargs.

Comment: I've added an example using a script

Comment: From man page, `-i` is deprecated; use `-I` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I find it much easier to divide the call to `xargs` into two, like this

```
seq 0 10 | xargs -n 3 | xargs -I {} echo foo {} bar
```

The first one has an implicit `echo` command, so the output will be

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 10
```

while in the second one the `-I` has an implicit `-L1`, picking one line at a time, given the desired output

```
foo 0 1 2 bar
foo 3 4 5 bar
foo 6 7 8 bar
foo 9 10 bar
```